# No restrictions to having vs no restriction to have

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following is correct?

1. There seems to be no restriction to having radio transmitters in the
   garden.
2. There seems to be no restriction to have radio transmitters
   in the garden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restriction on, as in limit
Barrier to, as in obstacle

There seems to be no restriction on having radio transmitters in the garden

Answer (score 1):

Neither are great. The optimal way to say it would be using a different word, like "radio transmitters seem to be permitted in the garden."

"There does not seem to be a restriction on the amount of radio transmitters you can have in the garden." works too.

I definitely do not think you should put "to" after "restriction".

If you insist on doing it this way, do something like this: "There seems to be no restrictions in regards to having radio transmitters in the garden"

"There seems to be no restrictions preventing you from having a radio transmitter in the garden"